# How to get an HTA application to accept command line arguments?

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
Sub Window_onLoad
    arrCommands = Split(ITTool.commandLine, chr(34))
    For i = 3 to (Ubound(arrCommands) - 1) Step 2
        MsgBox arrCommands(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run my HTA application, I get:

> arrCommands is undefined

I am trying to make an HTA app that [accepts command line arguments](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/20/how-can-i-pass-command-line-variables-to-an-hta-when-it-starts.aspx) (optional).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script section contains an [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29) statement. That makes defining variables before you can use them mandatory. Add a line `Dim arrCommands, i` to your procedure:

```
Sub Window_onLoad
    Dim arrCommands, i
    arrCommands = Split(ITTool.commandLine, chr(34))
    For i = 3 to (Ubound(arrCommands) - 1) Step 2
        MsgBox arrCommands(i)
    Next
End Sub
```